Improving MILP formulation (profitability based network design)
I have to design a network based on a profitability criteria, however I encounter some practical problems in the solving phase.
Formulation of the problem
We have a graph $G=(V, E)$, with subset $P$ of $V$ that are producers (with a production $p_i$, $i \in P$) and an other subest $C$ of $V$ that are customers (with a demand $d_i$, $i \in C$). Edges are generally bidirected, excepted for those connected with producers (they are only going out from the producers), and consumers (only going in the consumers). Furthermore there is only one edge entering a customer vertex. A cost $c_e$ and a maximum flow capacity $F_e$ are associated to every edge $e$.
Continuous variables $f_e \geq 0$ represent the physical flow on edge $e \in E$, binary variables $x_e$ represent the use of an edge $e \in E$ (ie there is a strictly positive flow $f_e$ on the edge $e$).
We want to minimize the following criteria :
$$
\min \sum_{e \in E} x_e c_e - \sum_{e \in E_C} f_e
$$
with $E_C$ the subset of edges leading to a consumer vertex, under the following constraints :
Note : with $i \in V$, $E_i^-$ and $E_i^+$ are respectively the subsets of egdes leaving and entering the vertex $i$.

Flow conservation :

$$
\forall i \in P, \space \sum_{e \in E_i^-} f_e \leq p_i
$$
$$
\forall i \in V \backslash (P \cup C) , \space \sum_{e \in E_i^+} f_e - \sum_{e \in E_i^-} f_e = 0
$$

Satisfaction of demand if the customer is connected to the network :
$$
\forall i \in C, \space E_i^+ = \{e\}, \space f_e = x_e d_i
$$
Maximum capacity constraint (big-M constraint) :
$$
\forall e \in E, \space f_e \leq F_e x_e
$$

Implementation
Here is my implementation (Python with Gurobi) of the problem :
def milp(nodes, edges, production, demand, costs, capacities):

    model = gp.Model("flow_milp")

    x = {}
    f = {}

    for (i, j) in edges:
        x[i, j] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name=f'x_{i}_{j}')
        f[i, j] = model.addVar(lb=0, ub=capacities[(i, j)], vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name=f'f_{i}_{j}')

    model.update()

    obj_expr = gp.LinExpr()
    for (i, j) in edges:
        obj_expr += costs[(i, j)] * x[i, j]
        if j in demand:
            obj_expr -= f[i, j]

    model.setObjective(obj_expr, GRB.MINIMIZE)

    for n in nodes:
        flow_in = gp.LinExpr()
        flow_out = gp.LinExpr()
        for (i, j) in edges:
            if j == n:
                flow_in += f[i, j]
            if i == n:
                flow_out += f[i, j]

        if n in production:
            model.addConstr(flow_out <= production[n], name=f'production_{n}')
        else:
            if n not in demand:
                model.addConstr(flow_in - flow_out == 0, name=f'flow_balance_{n}')

    for (i, j) in edges:
        if j in demand:
            model.addConstr(f[i, j] == x[i, j] * demand[j], name=f'demand_satisfaction_{i}_{j}')

    for (i, j) in edges:
        model.addConstr(f[i, j] <= capacities[(i, j)] * x[i, j], name=f'capacity_{i}_{j}')

    model.optimize()

    return model.status 

Problem encountered
In my usecase, the problem must be solved in a short time (less than 5 minutes on a machine with a processor 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11850H @ 2.50GHz, 2496 MHz, 8 cores, 16 logical processors), and it works very well on "small" and "medium" instances (up to 100 nodes and 500 edges) the problem being solved almost instantly.
However the final application needs to work on bigger instances, typically 10000 nodes and 50000 edges, which I can not handle at the moment in less than 5 minutes.
I think about the following improvements :

Avoiding big M constraints (even if I don't know how)
Try to simplify the input graph to reduce the number of variables
Use only one binary variable $x_e$ for a bidirected edge instead of two
Increase the MIP Gap, to have an approximation in a reasonable time (I obtained an acceptable solution on instances with 2500 nodes and 10000 edges in less than a minute with that method, but it doesn't work on bigger instances)

I am interested in any recommendation to improve my formulation or its implementation to speed up the calculations.

This is a curious cost function. It aims at minimizing the cost of each edges independently of the volume on the edge? Also Isn't the term $\sum_{e \in E_c} f_e$ constant (it equals the total demand) ? (in which case it can be removed from the cost function)

Also, the demand satisfaction constraint is suspicious. As it is, it states that the flow into a customer's node trough all incoming active arcs must be equal to its demand. So if there are $n$ incoming active arcs, the customer will receive $n$ times its demand $d_i$. Is this what you want? Maybe you want to add a constraint to ensure that there is only one active incoming arc? Or perhaps a sum, similar to the first constraint?

Costs are driven by digging expenses in my usecase (which are nearly fixed costs, independant of the volume). However gains are directly proportionnal to the delivered volumes. The righthand term in the objective is not constant since it is equal to the customer's demand if we are connected to the client and 0 if not.

About the demand satisfaction constraint, there is only one edge entering in any customer by definition of my graph (and no edge leaving the customer), sorry if it was not clear in my formulation.

so if a customer is not connected to the network, how can its demand be satisfied?

Are you ok with the fact that the 2 terms in your objective function do not have the same unit? (costs vs demands). you may want to add the profit coefficient for each demand in the second term

We do not want to satisfy all the demands, only the ones that induce a minimization of our objective function. That's a way to select the customers.

I tried to simply the formulation to leave aside the usecase relative details. But of course you need to add coefficients to make everything fine.

If you are willing to accept a good but not necessarily optimal solution, here are a couple of things you could try.

Set an acceptable (to you) time limit and use parameters to tell Gurobi to emphasize improving the primal bound/applying heuristics and deemphasize improving the dual bound/proving optimality.
Using a rounding heuristic. Solve the LP relaxation, pick a binary variable, fix it at its rounded (integer) variable, re-optimize the LP, round another variable, etc. until all integer variables have been fixed.


Thank you very much ! Indeed I think I have to work more on Gurobi parameters to get "good" solutions quickly.

Some things you could try (if you are willing to sacrifice global optimality):

sparsify the graph by removing "expensive" edges. Define "expensive" with a parameter, and try running the problem with different values. For example if the the cost $c_e$ is greater than a parameter $\alpha$, remove the edge from the network.
identify edges that you "know" will be used in the solution (e.g. important edges entering a customer's node, or "important" intermediate edges, or edges with very low cost $c_e$), and for such edges, add $x_e =1$ to the problem.
add more structure to your solution, by imposing additional constraints such as $\sum_e x_e \ge \beta$, where $\beta$ is a parameter that you have to tune as well.
perform a change of variables and work with paths instead of edges. This means you pre-define a pool of "good" paths, and solve the problem as a packing problem. Alternatively, start with a reasonable subset of paths, and use column generation to find "better" paths dynamically.


Thank you for your suggestions ! What is the effect of adding structure to the solution as you proposed ? Is it a way to reduce the solving time ? If so, it seems to be very practical in my application.

Adding structure will reduce the search space (the number of feasible solutions). It is very hard to predict whether this will decrease the computation time or not, but it may be worth a try.
